# Parallel.Invoke works slowly

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task

I wrote code Methode #1 and Methode #2 for compare performance. Methode #1 use construnction for, and Methode #2 using Parallel.Invoke.  In second scenario works very slowly. I can't understand why it was happening ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using Mpir.NET;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        public class numbers
        {
            public numbers(mpz_t p, mpz_t q)
            {
                this.q = q;
                this.p = p;
            }
            mpz_t q;
            mpz_t p;
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Int32 arraySize = 400;
            ConcurrentBag<numbers> pairsCB = new ConcurrentBag<numbers>();
            ConcurrentBag<Action> cbTasks = new ConcurrentBag<Action>();
            HashSet<numbers> uniqueCB = new HashSet<numbers>(pairsCB.ToArray());

            mpz_t[] numbersArray = new mpz_t[arraySize];

            for (Int32 i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
            {
                numbersArray[i] = i*i+i+1; 
            }


            //Methode #1 
            Stopwatch stopwatch1 = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch1.Start();

            for (Int32 j = 0; j < arraySize; j++)
            {
                checkDivisible(numbersArray[j], pairsCB);
            }

            uniqueCB = new HashSet<numbers>(pairsCB.ToArray());
            stopwatch1.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Methode Count Unique Pairs  Count:{0}\tTime elapsed:{1}", uniqueCB.Count(), stopwatch1.Elapsed);

            //Methode #2 
            Stopwatch stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch2.Start();
            pairsCB = new ConcurrentBag<numbers>();

            for(Int32 j = 0; j < arraySize; j++)
            {
                mpz_t value = numbersArray[j];
                cbTasks.Add(new Action(() => checkDivisible(value, pairsCB)));
            }

            Action[] tasks =  cbTasks.ToArray();

            Parallel.Invoke(tasks);

            stopwatch2.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Methode Count Unique Pairs  Count:{0}\tTime elapsed:{1}", uniqueCB.Count(), stopwatch2.Elapsed);


            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void checkDivisible(mpz_t n, ConcurrentBag<numbers>  pq)
        {
            mpz_t p = 1; 
            mpz_t q = 1;    

            for (Int32 i = 2; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (n % i == 0)
                {
                    q = i;
                    p = n / i;
                    pq.Add(new numbers(p, q));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's simply because this method is very small and you get an overhead for creating threads. only use parallelism when you have really long processes (file access, downloads, massive calculations, etc...)

Comment: If a task doesn't last at least let's say 0.1 second, it's useless to parallelize it. It's more time to schedule it than to run it.

Comment: ConcurrentBag isn't a general purpose collection, it's used to store data locally for each thread that writes to it. In any case, since you are using Parellel.Invoke, you don't need a concurrent collection at all for the tasks. Use ConcurrentQueue for the numbers. Better yet, avoid using a common collection completely by returning a `numbers` array from each call and merging them at the end - that's essentially the `reduce` step in any map/reduce algorithm

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos - can you provide optimized code? I don't know how to return array in Parallel.Invoke and merge data.  I would like use Parallel.Invoke for understanding how  it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many reasons why the second method is slower.

1. `checkDivisible` doesn't do enough work to justify parallelization. The overhead of parallelization and synchronization may be greater than any benefit.
2. ConcurrentBag is a special-purpose collection that stores data in thread-local storage, ensuring a thread can quickly access the items it wrote. It's actually slower than the other concurrent collections in other scenarios.
3. All calls to `checkDivisible` write to the same collection, which becomes a hotspot. It's better to return a simple array from each call and merge all arrays in the end, in a final step.
4. Too many concurrent calls. Parallel.Invoke has to schedule each Action separately. `Parallel.For` or `Parallel.ForEach` on the other hand know all calls are the same, so they can partition the data according to the number of processors, ensuring the parallelization overhead is minimum.

The first step is to modify `checkDivisible`:

```
    private static List<number> checkDivisible(mpz_t n)
    {
        mpz_t p = 1; 
        mpz_t q = 1;    

        List<number> nums=new List<numbers>();

        for (Int32 i = 2; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (n % i == 0)
            {
                q = i;
                p = n / i;
                nums.Add(new numbers(p, q));
            }
        }
        return numbers;
    }
```

I would prefer the iterator method because it avoids creating a List just to collect the results.

Then you can use Parallel.For :

```
var results=new ConcurrentQueue<IList<numbers>>();

Parallel.For(0, arraySize, (index) => 
{
     var local=checkDivisible(numbersArray[index]);
     results.Add(local);
});

var final=results.SelectMany(r=>r).ToList();
```

The final step can be whatever you want to ensure the results are in the form you want , eg. use ToDictionary or ToLookup to merge results according to a key.

Another option is to use PLINQ to do the same thing in a more concise way. Changing `checkDivision` to an iterator:

```
    private static IEnumerable<number> checkDivisible(mpz_t n)
    {
        mpz_t p = 1; 
        mpz_t q = 1;    

        for (Int32 i = 2; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (n % i == 0)
            {
                q = i;
                p = n / i;
                yield return new numbers(p, q);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can write:

```
var results= (from n in numbersArray.AsParallel()
             from number in checkDivisible(n)
             select n).ToList();
```

Just as with Parallel.For, PLINQ will partition the data in `numbersArray` according to the number of cores on the machine, process the partitions in parallel and finally merge them in a list.

Comment: Please, can you provide right code for Parallel.Invoke. I understand Parallel.For is better, but I would like user Parallel.Invoke.

Comment: @YuriyTigiev why? What are you trying to solve? Running a separate task for each number is simply wrong, but that's what Invoke will do. You would have to rewrite what `Parallel.For` already does - partition the data, process each partition with Parallel.Invoke and finally collect the results. You can do that using the [Partitioner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner(v=vs.110).aspx) class or simply split your array indices into ranges and use the ranges (from,to) as inputs to your function

Comment: I'm testing new method for factorize numbers. I would like have mechanism for save state each task and mechanism load state for continue task from interapted step.

Comment: I need call special function 16384^2 times for factorize numbers.  What is optimal scheme for this case ? Use Parallel.For, PLINQ, Tasks ?

Answer (score 2):

Alternative you can use:

```
//Methode #2 
Stopwatch stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch2.Start();
pairsCB = new ConcurrentBag<numbers>();

Parallel.For(0, arraySize, (index) => 
{
     checkDivisible(numbersArray[index], pairsCB);
});

stopwatch2.Stop();
```

Output with arraySize = 1000

```
Methode Count Unique Pairs  Count:3878  Time elapsed:00:00:01.5671572
Methode Count Unique Pairs  Count:3878  Time elapsed:00:00:00.7917211
```

Comment: @YuriyTigiev as you can see from the comments and the other answer this would not bring any benefit in this case. if you have much bigger calculations to run it may have.

Comment: @YuriyTigiev that's the wrong method to call in this case (processings a lot of data in parallel) and it shows in the benchmarks. Partitioning the source data is important, something that Parallel.Invoke doesn't do

Comment: In real programm I would use a lot of calculations in checkDivisible.

Comment: @YuriyTigiev Parallel.For might be faster even then though... I'd test it and run a benchmark to be sure...

Comment: @YuriyTigiev rather update your question or add comments

Comment: @YuriyTigiev as we mentioned before adding parallelism to this is not a really good idea... i changed the arraySize to 1000 before i could see a performance boost

Comment: @YuriyTigiev im running on a intel i3 here... what kind of cpu do you have?

Comment: My home notebook 

Intel  I7-3537U 2GHZ 4Core
RAM 4 GB 
OS: Win 8.1 64 bit 
Visual Studio  2015 CTP 6

Int32 arraySize = 300;
Methode Count Unique Pairs  Count:902   Time elapsed:00:00:16.7223979
Methode Count Unique Pairs  Count:902   Time elapsed:00:00:16.7882786

Comment: Screw up the array size to 1000 and try again

Comment: @YuriyTigiev and are you compiling the project with 64bits?